# Find scsi device ids under Linux?

Tags: linux, scsi

How can I list scsi device ids under Linux?

Comment: Please take my previous comment about how to ask good questions seriously! Drop the "hi" and "thanks", make sure the first few lines or the question introduce the question instead of being meta data so that the home page summaries are useful, and **always show what attempts you have made to solve problems yourself**. I answered this question by copy and pasting a bit of it into google and copy and pasting a bit from the result summaries back to you (after checking it in my terminal).

Comment: _SCSI ID_ is not precisely defined thing, reference this discussion http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/scsi_ids.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cat /proc/scsi/scsi
```

Comment: This does not show which SCSI ids correspond to which system devices.

Comment: Also it doesn't exist any more.

Comment: @MatthiasUrlichs does exist for me on `5.18.6-zen1-1-zen`. Perhaps you kernel has some setting disabled that creates that dir.

Answer (score 11):

I don't have /proc/scsi/scsi on my system with 2.6.39.1 kernel. I would use 'lsscsi' command:

```
~> lsscsi -v
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST3500418AS      CC38  /dev/sda
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:0:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0]
[1:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD2500KS-00M 02.0  /dev/sdb
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/1:0:0:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0]
```

Comment: 2.6.38.6 here and I do have it. I wonder if there is a kernel config option for providing that interface. The reference I found to using that proc entry was as old as the hills. Also my distro doesn't have `lsscsi` by default although I see there is an optional package for it.

Comment: To add, modern `lsblk -S` can show HOST:CHANNEL:TARGET:LUN numbers too.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the links in `/dev/disk/by-id`:

```
[root@krxl02cn05 by-id]# pwd
/dev/disk/by-id

[root@krxl02cn05 by-id]# ls -rtl
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Feb 12 01:40 scsi-3600605b005d8655019aa31faf0812bae -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb 12 01:40 scsi-3600605b005d8655019aa31faf0812bae-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb 12 01:40 scsi-3600605b005d8655019aa31faf0812bae-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Feb 12 01:50 scsi-3600144f09a214698000054db88550008 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Feb 12 01:50 scsi-3600144f09a214698000054db88460007 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Feb 12 01:50 scsi-3600144f09a214698000054db88260006 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb 12 01:54 scsi-3600144f09a214698000054db88260006-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Feb 12 04:56 scsi-3600144f09a214698000054db88460007-part1 -> ../../asm-disk1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Feb 12 04:59 scsi-3600144f09a214698000054db88550008-part1 -> ../../asm-disk2
```

So, the scsi id of `/dev/sdc` is `3600144f09a214698000054db88460007`

Comment: Incorrectly downvoted answer. `by-id` shows WWID which is valid SCSI identificator, even though `by-id` not necessarily shows all disks. Sometimes, `/dev/disk/by-path` can show SCSI Ids too. Example `ls -l /dev/disk/by-path` outputs  `pci-0000:00:07.1-scsi-1:0:0:0 -> ../../sr0`. So, `sr0` have SCSI Host:BUS:Target_ID:LUN `1:0:0:0`. This is not SCSI disk, though.

Comment: Actually, `lsscsi --scsi_id` shows `scsi-*` matching id from `/dev/disk/by-id` (if present).